# Flutter apk doesn't work in android device

Tags: android, flutter, apk

I try to generate apk file for my flutter app, I used `flutter build apk --release` command after `flutter clean` command.
note that after used `flutter build apk --release` command I got this error:

```
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\android_intent-0.3.7+3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\androidintent\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher-5.4.5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\urllauncher\WebViewActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

After that, I got the apk file from this path: `C:\project_path\build\app\outputs\apk\release`, but when I try to install this apk from the mobile I got this `app not installed`:

[image]

**note: I'm tried more than one device with a different android version.**

Please help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be warnings, not errors, thus the apk should be generated.

In any case, did you check the hardware architecture?

For example, try to specify the architecture for your smartphone:

flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm64

flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm  ( <-- arm 32 bits)

etc...

Comment: Hi @Mike, My smartphone 64-bit ARMv8-A I've tried this command (flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm64) but I still get "app not installed".

Comment: I don't know, you can build the apk, and copy it to GDrive and install it manually on your smartphone, it works. If you have your smartphone connected to the PC using the USB cable, then a simple flutter run  should work: flutter run will install the app to your device ( select the smartphone using flutter devices ) in debug mode.